# How C# connection to Access DB without MS Access?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

What do I need to do so that I can work with Access DB database file in C# without installing MS Access?

I make a program for a computer on which MS Access is not installed

Comment: You don't need MS-Access. You need only the ADO.NET provider required by your connectionstring (or by the bitness of your application)

Comment: Do you have to use MS Acces, do you _want_ to use MS Access or didn't you even consider alternatives?

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms?view=vs-2019) was literally one <put in search engine> away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to install the office setup in your system, but you do need to install either the ACE or the JET engine driver with the correct bit version to use Access files in your code. The 32 bit engine driver will not work with 64 bit OS version and vice versa.

Have a look here:

for download and instruction
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255

for access connecetion strings
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: You should also add the fact that if the app is 32 bit using the old MDB file format then there is nothing to install apart from the NET Framework itself